# Prove that a group of odd order doesn't have two conjugate inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let G be a group of odd order $(|G|=2k+1,k\in\mathbb N)$. Prove that does not exist $a\in G$ s.t $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are conjugated, means $\exists g\in G:g^{-1}ag=a^{-1}$

Suppose we have group G with odd order, assume $\exists a\in G$ which is conjugated to its inverse ($\exists g\in G:g^{-1}ag=a^{-1}$). I though building homomorphism $\psi:G\to G$ based on conjugation ($\psi(l)=g_l^{-1}\cdot g\cdot g_l$). Then in fact $e=\psi(e)=\psi(a\cdot a^{-1})=\psi(a)\psi(a^{-1})$ and there to get somehow contradiction. My only problem is I don't know how to get it.  Maybe I had to define a isomorphism and get contradiction to its basic properties (e.g sends cylcic sources to cyclic ranges)?

Comment: Maple has the [GroupTheory:-IsSimple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GroupTheory/IsSimple) command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we must exclude $a = e$, since of course $g^{-1} e g = e = e^{-1}$.

Then, suppose you had an $a \in G\setminus \{e\}$ and a $g \in G$ with $g^{-1} a g = a^{-1}$. Let $\psi_g(x) = g^{-1}xg$. Then $\psi_g^{\operatorname{ord} g} = \operatorname{id}$. But look what $\psi_g^{\operatorname{ord} g}$ would do to $a$.

Comment: +1 Another algorithm may be that if the finite group $G$ has a proper subgroup $H$ of finite index, say $n$, such that $|G|$ doesn't divide $n!/2$, then $G$ is not simple.

Comment: @Daniel, How $\psi^{ordg}=id$ ?
Babak: Suppose G is not simple, how does it help proving the claim?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis Because $\psi_g^k$ is conjugation by $g^k$, and $g^{\operatorname{ord}g} = e$. Conjugation by $e$ is the identity.

Comment: but if $o(g)=k,o(a)=k+1$, then $\psi^k$ sends $a\mapsto a^{-o(g)}$ and then psi^k acts like identity since $e=a^{o(g)+1},a=a^{-o(g)}$. This occuraion can't happen since g depends on a?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis Since $\lvert G\rvert$ is odd, all orders of elements are odd. Besides, $\psi_g^k(a) = a^{(-1)^k}$, not $a^{-k}$.